# limiting file extension in django form file upload

Tags: django, forms, file-upload

I have forms.Form in django. In this form there is a forms.FileField. This field is rendered in html as

```
<input id="id_upload-loaded_file" name="upload-loaded_file" type="file">
```

I need to add accepted files only with ".zip" extension  so that form will be rendered as

```
<input id="id_upload-loaded_file" name="upload-loaded_file" type="file" accept=".zip">
```

How can I add accepted file extension attribute in django?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it:

```
zip_file = forms.FileField(label='Select zip file', widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': '.zip'}))
```